# "Undefined control sequence" at beginning of document with moderncv

Tags: errors, moderncv, document-classes

I'm trying to use `moderncv`. When I try to compile the following document

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

I get 8 times the error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
```

When I use any other documentclass, such as `article` or `report` everything works. I'm using texlive with texstudio on ubuntu and I compiled with PdfLaTeX.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: I get a different error, but the key here is that `moderncv` requires you to set up things in the preamble, which you have not done.  Try `\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello.
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

Well, class `moderncv` is different to the usual one class `article` etc.

Because it is supposed to typeset a curriculum vitae, there are more information needed than in an "usual" class.

Because a cv needs a name of the person the cv is for you have to add the information

```
\name{John}{Doe}
```

Now you can compile your MWE with an added `\name{John}{Doe}` without errors but not with the layout of a cv:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

That has compiled without errors, but is far away from a cv ...

To get a real cv you have to add more informations, for example the style of the layout. Then you need to add informations about education etc.  Class `moderncv` provides special commands for that.

The absolut minimal code for an cv with `moderncv` is the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
 \moderncvstyle{classic} % 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
 \moderncvcolor{blue}    % 'black' (default)

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
%\title{Resumé title}
%\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
%\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
%\email{john@doe.org}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 

Hello.  % <========= to be deleted!

\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

I used the original `template.tex` file (an cv example) from `moderncv` and minimalized it.  As you can see in the compiled following MWE, your input "Hello." makes no sense now ...

The result you get is:

[image: resulting cv]